# Inno Setup Unicode encoding issue with messages in ISS script

Tags: unicode, character-encoding, inno-setup

We have a script setup to run with Inno Setup Unicode compiler. The installer at the moment supports English, German and French.

It has been brought to our attention that the encoding for our custom messages in French aren't correct. The custom message files are saved as UTF-8 so there should not have been an encoding issue. We verified we were using the Unicode compiler and not ANSI by accident.

[image]

Expected Custom message:

> `French.UninstallOldVersionPrompt=Il semble y avoir une version antérieure de Rubberduck installée sur ce système pour %s.There seems to be a previous version of Rubberduck, qui devra d'abord être désinstallée. Procéder à la désinstallation?`

[Link to source](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/blob/next/Rubberduck.Deployment/InnoSetup/Includes/French.CustomMessages.iss)

The file is saved as UTF-8, so it shouldn't have had encoding issues. What went wrong?

For more details, you can read up on the [Github issue](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/issues/3946)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `.iss` file needs to have [UTF-8 BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), if it includes Unicode/UTF-8 strings.

In your case, it's the `French.CustomMessages.iss` that is missing the BOM.

The `German.CustomMessages.iss` has the BOM, that's why it works correctly with German.

See also [UTF-8 characters not displaying correctly in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51066207/850848).

---

The [BOM requirement is now properly documented](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptformatoverview):

> If an Unicode file is used, it must be UTF-8 encoded with a BOM.

Comment: Confirmed this works. Thanks for the help! Hopefully they'll update the documentation to reflect that fact; it's fairly uncommon to require BOMs.

Comment: Hopefully the BOM requirement will be removed. The Eclipse IDE (Java) 'only' supports UTF-8 /without/ BOM. My path of least resistance was to set the resource encoding to ISO8859-1.

Comment: The BOM requirement is documented in both the [Creating Installations](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=creatinginstallations) and the [Script Format Overview](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptformatoverview) topics. However, I'm working on removing the requirement.