# UTF-8 characters not displaying correctly in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I've seen a couple of other threads about this but I've spent a while trying to get it sorted to no avail.

Here's a generic version of my .iss file:

```
; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define AppName "MyApp"
#define CompanyName "MyCompany"
#define FileName "File Name"
#define AppExeName "App Exe.exe"
#define AppIcon "..\icon.ico"
#define AppId "app.id"
#define AppURL "mywebsite"
#define AppSrcDir "path\to\app\directory"
#define AppTargetDir "{userappdata}\" + CompanyName + "\" + AppName
#define AppVersion GetFileVersion(AppSrcDir + "\" + AppExeName)
#define AppPublisher "Publisher"
#define LaunchMessage "Launch Message"
#define AppProtocol "protocol"
#define OutputDir "path\to\output"
#define SetupFilename FileName + "-setup-" + AppVersion
#define SetupImage "..\setup.bmp"
#define InstallerMessage "Some message with a German character - ö"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application.
; Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)

AllowCancelDuringInstall=no
AppId={#AppId}
AppName={#AppName}
AppVersion={#AppVersion}
AppVerName={#AppName} {#AppVersion}
AppPublisher={#AppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#AppURL}
AppSupportURL={#AppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#AppURL}
DefaultDirName={#AppTargetDir}
DefaultGroupName={#CompanyName}
DisableDirPage=yes
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
DisableReadyPage=yes
DisableReadyMemo=yes
OutputDir={#OutputDir}
OutputBaseFilename={#SetupFilename}
PrivilegesRequired=lowest
SetupIconFile={#AppIcon}
SignTool=signtool
Compression=lzma/ultra64
SolidCompression=yes
WizardSmallImageFile={#SetupImage}
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\{#AppExeName}

[InstallDelete]
Type: filesandordirs; Name: {#AppTargetDir}

[Languages]
Name: de; MessagesFile: "compiler:Languages\German.isl"

[Files]
Source: "{#AppSrcDir}\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: recursesubdirs
Source: "path\to\other\installers\win32\*"; DestDir: "{app}\redist";
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#AppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#AppExeName}"; WorkingDir: "{app}";
Name: "{commondesktop}\{#AppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#AppExeName}"; WorkingDir: "{app}";

[Run]
FileName: "{app}\redist\installer.exe"; Parameters: "/S /v/qn"; WorkingDir: "{app}"; StatusMsg: "{#InstallerMessage}";
```

The problem I have is that it doesn't display the `InstallerMessage` text correctly. The `ö` character does not render correctly.

I am using the Unicode version of Inno Setup (with the "(u)").

I have seen some mentions of using a byte order mark but I haven't seen any examples. I tried converting the whole string using a UTF-8 encoder and added the byte order mark at the start but it didn't work. I'm completely stumped!

Answer (score 14):

Make sure your `.iss` file uses UTF-8 encoding *with BOM*.

And of course, you need Unicode version of Inno Setup (the only version as of Inno Setup 6).

---

Was the string also used in Pascal Script code (what is not, mentioning it just for benefit of others, who may find this question), you also have to use [Inno Setup 5.6.0](https://jrsoftware.org/files/is5-whatsnew.htm#5.6.0) or later. Earlier versions did not support UTF-8 in Pascal Script.

> Pascal Scripting changes:
> Unicode Inno Setup: Unicode is now supported for the input source. For example, where before you had to write `S := #$0100 + #$0101 + 'Aa';` you can now write `S := 'ĀāAa';` directly. Also see the new *UnicodeExample1.iss* example script.

---

See also [Inno Setup Unicode encoding issue with messages in ISS script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49922735/850848).

Comment: Yes, the same applies to a license file that iss may import. UTF-8 with BOM for this file is also required to correctly render non-ASCII characters. Many thanks to @Reverate for the tip on how to convert it quickly with VSCode.